# StackNavigation unable to find the screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

While writing a demo stacknavigation app I am encountering an error on semulator stating 
" Route 'Main' should declare a screen. For example:

import MyScreen from './MyScreen';
...
Main: {
  screen: MyScreen,
}

    C:\RN\blog\node_modules\react-navigation\src\routers\validateRouteConfigMap.js:23:8
validateRouteConfigMap
    C:\RN\blog\node_modules\react-navigation\src\routers\validateRouteConfigMap.js:18:21
default
    C:\RN\blog\node_modules\react-navigation\src\routers\StackRouter.js:47:25
default
    C:\RN\blog\node_modules\react-navigation\src\navigators\StackNavigator.js:51:29
......
"

Why this is happening I don't know can anybody has any idea ?
The remain code are below

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

import MainScreen from './MainScreen';
import RegisterScreen from './RegisterScreen';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const ScreenList = StackNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: MainScreen,
    },
    Register: {
        screen: RegisterScreen,
    },
});

export default ScreenList;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import MainScreen from './src/screens/MainScreen';
import ScreenList from './src/screens/ScreenList';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ScreenList />
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Card, Button, CardSection } from '../components/common/Index';
import Login from '../components/Login';
import ScreenList from './ScreenList';



export default class MainScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Card>
                    <Login />
                </Card>
                <Text>----------------------------------</Text>
                <Card>
                    <CardSection>
                        <Button>Register</Button>
                    </CardSection>
                </Card>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe its an issue with imports. Try removing
`import MainScreen from './src/screens/MainScreen';`
 from App.js or wherever it is. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

A guess, maybe you have not exported `MainScreen` Component.It will help if you can share the mainScreen file code.

Comment: Hey again please I added MainScreen Code now

Comment: Remove `import MainScreen from './src/screens/MainScreen';
` from App.js or wherever it is. it should work.